# GCS Read from a text file from google cloud to python jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-storage

Hello in my GCP jupyter notebook I am reading

```
from google.cloud import storage
client = storage.Client()
BUCKET_NAME = 'sleep-accel'
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
blobs_all = list(bucket.list_blobs())
blobs_specific = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='physionet.org/files/sleep-accel/1.0.0/motion/'))
for doc in blobs_specific:
    print(doc)
```

dataset that I loaded in to GCS and for some reason its printing

```
<Blob: sleep-accel, physionet.org/files/sleep-accel/1.0.0/motion/1455390_acceleration.txt, 1656705245042882>
```

how can I access the .txt files ?

Because my main/end goal is to convert the content of .txt into a single .csv format

Answer (score 0):

Converting the **.txt** files to **.csv format** can be achieved by using the `pandas` module.

Below is my sample code converting txt files from the bucket to csv format

```py
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd


client = storage.Client()
BUCKET_NAME = 'your_bucket_name'
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)

blobs_specific = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='physionet.org/files/sleep-accel/1.0.0/motion/'))

#List all the objects inside physionet.org/files/sleep-accel/1.0.0/motion/ folder 
for doc in list(blobs_specific)[1:]:
    #read the txt files using pandas and remove the header and separate it using space
    df = pd.read_csv("gs://your_bucket_file_path/" + doc.name, header=None, sep=' ')
    #change the doc.name value .txt to .csv
    to_csv = doc.name.replace('.txt','.csv')
    print(to_csv)
    #convert the txt files to csv using pandas and save it to physionet.org/files/sleep-accel/1.0.0/motion/ folder in your notebook
    df.to_csv(to_csv, index=False,  sep=',')
```

the **csv** file will be downloaded to your `notebook` local server.

Note: you need to create a directory tree like this: `physionet.org/files/sleep-accel/1.0.0/motion/` in your `notebook` because this is where the csv file will be saved.