# How to use pd.read_csv() with Blobs from GCS?

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-storage

I have python script reading files from GCS bucket

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('sa.json')
BUCKET_NAME = 'sleep-accel'
bucket = client.get_bucket(BUCKET_NAME)
blobs_all = list(bucket.list_blobs())
blobs_specific = list(bucket.list_blobs(prefix='physionet.org/files/sleep-accel/1.0.0/motion/'))
main_df = pd.DataFrame({})
txtFile = blobs_specific[0].download_to_file('/tmp')
main_df = pd.concat([main_df, pd.read_csv(txtFile)])
```

blobs_specific returns array of blobs with contain a blob with few metadata and the .txt file that i need to get parsed by .read_csv();

I'm trying to figure out which GCS library function I'm suppose to use so that pd.read_csv() can read it

All the files are in .txt and thats why im trying to parse it to .csv here

Comment: Are you able to share a couple of lines from the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCS Read from a text file from google cloud to python jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889102/gcs-read-from-a-text-file-from-google-cloud-to-python-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: **download_to_file('/tmp')**. tmp is a directory and not a file like object.  That API is also deprecated. You probably want to use **download_to_filename()**.